# Javascript echo'd by PHP doesn't run

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, echo

I am having a little issue with echoing javascript dynamically via php. Here is my code

```
$url = "http://www.newsite.com";

echo "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Redirecting</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='redirect()'>
        Not Logged In

        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function redirect() {
        window.location=".$url."
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

My javascript console is telling me that "redirect()" cant be found (Uncaught ReferenceError: redirect is not defined)

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Maybe window.location='".$url."'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a quotation mark. This will fix your issue:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location='".$url."';
}
```

Currently, your page is rendered as follows (note the missing quotes / syntax error):

```
function redirect() {
    window.location=http://www.newsite.com;
}
```

Comment: That was it. I know it was something silly like that :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I can! (which is 5 minutes apparently >.>)

Comment: My answer answers your question, but you should consider the method as provided by Tomalak. Especially for redirecting, you should use the header method. If not, at least add a link in the document, in case the user has disabled JavaScript (eg by [NoScript](http://noscript.net))

Comment: In the grand scheme of the code, that's not possible, since this will be run in an iframe (requirement of the service I will be running this on), and I need to access the `top` window location, and `header` will only affect the iframe.

But yes, I do agree that his method is a better way, but Javascript is a necessity for now.

Comment: @Esaevian Then, use `top.window.location.href = '".$url."';`. Still, consider my other point: Provide a link (`<a href='$url' target='_top'>Redirecting...</a>`) for the users who have disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Drop that client-based redirect entirely. Use:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify (since it's kind of out of the scope of the general question), but I need javascript since this will run inside and iframe, and the `header` call will only affect the iframe's location, while I need to modify the `top` location (will update my js to modify top, I changed it to `window` just to make sure that `top` wasn't the problem for some reason (perhaps not the best approach to debugging...)

Answer (score 2):

The code has problem.

```
window.location=".$url."
```

should be

```
window.location=\"".$url."\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place that function in the heading area ane wrap it like so.

```
echo "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Redirecting</title>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function redirect() {
        window.location='".$url."."'
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='redirect()'>
        Not Logged In


    </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tomalak says, you should not be using javascript to solve this problem. Use a server redirect.

However, there is a more general problem with getting php data into javascript. I'll solve that problem here.

You need to escape the `$url` parameter properly for both javascript AND html.  `redirect()` is not defined because there's a syntax error in it.

Whenever you need to pass javascript data inline into html, use the following pattern. It is the clearest, safest way to do this.

```
<?php
// 1. put all the data you want into a single object
$data = compact($url);
// $data === array('url'=>'http://example.org')

// 2. Convert that object to json
$jsdata = json_encode($url);

// 3. html-escape it for inclusion in a script tag
$escjsdata = htmlspecialchars($jsdata, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
// change utf-8 to whatever encoding you are using in your html.'
// I hope for your sanity you are using utf-8!

// 4. Now assign $escjsdata to a js variable in your html:

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
</head>
<body onload='redirect()'>
    Not Logged In

    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function redirect() {
        var data = <?php echo $escjsdata ?>;

        window.location=data.url;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```