# Parsing php values to javascript Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript echo’d by PHP doesn’t run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360008/javascript-echod-by-php-doesnt-run)

In the following code I am parsing values from a php table into a javascript function, however I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: "the php text" is not defined (anonymous function)

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function draw(name ) {
            alert(name);
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width=800 height=400></canvas>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM graph_table';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($val = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name =  $val['test_name'];
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">    draw('.$name .');          </script>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** JavaScript code. I'm sure it looks like `draw(sometext)`, where you actually want to have `draw("sometext")`.

Comment: Get the view source of the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add quote's between `draw` since you're passing text to it. `draw(\''.$name.'\');` will make your problem go away.

Comment: It works! Thankyou so much, when I was parsing an int there wasn't a problem so I figured it must be a string thing but I didn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM graph_table';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($val = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name =  $val['test_name'];
             echo "draw('$name');";
        }
?>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the php script inside . Mainly you should add js script just before .